# getting junk characters in IMAP

Tags: php, imap

I am getting junk characters when using php IMAP like

```
<b>Text in bold</b> getting converted to *Text in bold* 
 words like shouldn't are getting converted to shouldn=92t
```

the code I am using is

```
$inbox = imap_open('host', 'un', 'pw') or die('Cannot connect to Mail box: ' . print_r(imap_errors()));
$mails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');
if($mails) {
    foreach($mails as $mail) {
        echo $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $mail, 1);
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
imap_close($inbox);
```

can some one help me to find whats the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

You run into two different problems:

The text in bold is simply because the html in the mail is interpreted by the browser. To avoid this, you can escape the content with [htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) or [htmlspecialchars()](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

"shouldn=92t" is a quoted-printable encoded string. This has to be decoded to be readable - can be done with [quoted_printable_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-decode.php) or [imap_qprint()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php)

Comment: thanks for the hint. I got #2 solved. but still stuck at #1. Changed the code to $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $mail, 1); echo imap_qprint(htmlspecialchars($body, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")); ' and its now output the data as *anchor text*

Since stack overflow is stripping the code, please see this http://pastebin.com/zEtG1fRx

Comment: Wait, I thought the problem is that html in the body text got interpreted by the browser. But your problem is, that you want "`any *text*`" converted to "`any <b>text</b>`"?

Comment: no. my problem is exactly the html interpretation. Suppose I am sending a reply from gmail with a <b>bold</b> word in the reply, then when I read it via IMAP, its getting converted to *bold *. So even if I save it to the database, its getting saved as *bold * instead of getting saved as <b>bold</b>. Same with anchor tags also.